# How do I know my git repository is same as my Mercurial repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, mercurial, repository, bitbucket

I converted my Mercurial repository(in Bitbucket) to git (gitLab), I am wondering that how can I know that no files/comments were missing? How to check if two repositories are the same?

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot [compare SHA1 hashes between Git and Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55478181/6309) (they would be different anyway)

But you can at least script and compare:

- the [list of revision in Hg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791903/how-can-i-list-a-series-of-revisions-using-hg-log) (with their comment)
- `git log` (which includes comment)

And see if the list has the same number of elements and if the comments matches

For each commit, you can:

- list [the files in a given Hg revision](http://hg%20status%20--change%20%3Crev%3E) (`hg status --change <rev>`)
- list [the files a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444317/6309)

And make sure each one:

- has the same number of files.
- has the same content, by comparing them with a diff tool ([kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) or, as suggested below, [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/?lang=en) if you are on Windows)

Using a diff tool alone is not enough: you need to do it revision by revision.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of the original HG and new Git repos locally, you can use a program like WinMerge to diff both folder trees.

Excluding the "internal" files like `.hg` you should find an identical set of files at the heads of both.

Personally I like this approach because it is independent of the source control systems themselves. If you don't fully trust the Git conversion in the first place, I think its sensible to check the "facts on the ground" directly without going through any extra intermediate steps.